# C# webBrowser automatic submit button click not working

Tags: c#

I have a button in HTML as such:

```
<input id="accept” class="accept button" type="submit" name="authorize" value="Log in" style>
```

The code below not working.

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");  
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)  
{  
   if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))  
   {  
        el.InvokeMember("Click");  
   }  
 }
```

I have also tried:

```
          HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
            foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("accept"))
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
```

But no success.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this?

```
var lLink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".accept.button"));
lLink.Click();
```

[look doc](https://www.seleniumstutorial.com/selenium-c-find-element-classname/)

Comment: its not selenium. its just a webbrowser in winform

Comment: web browser yes. but you specify and direct these browser features. I guess you don't have an idea about what happened to the web driver. take a look
  [link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_browser_drivers/)